# How make select option value start over everytime changing its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

i've been making 2 select option box. Which is worked, the first one is ranged between 2010-2019. The second one, i wanted it to start from the value of the first select option box with its range +10 years.

Yes it did worked! But the problem is, if i did my first choose it worked. Then when i change the first option box value, it gave me another loop.
For example : 
First option box i choose :  2011
Second option box value will be : 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, .. ,2021.

Then i click the first option box to be : 2012
Second option box value will be : 2011,2012, 2013,2014,..,2021, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, .., 2022.

Here's the code i've been made.

```js
<script>
/*  NILAI TAHUN BERLAKU SAMPAI BERDASAR TAHUN BERLAKU MULAI */
  $("#idTahunBerlaku").change(
    function() {
     var startkiri = parseInt($(this).val());
     var start = startkiri;
     var end = startkiri + 10;
     var options = "";
     for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
      options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
     }
     document.getElementById("idTahunBerlakuS")
       .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);
    });
  
  var start = 2010;
  var end = 2019;
  var options = "";
  for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
   options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
  }
  document.getElementById("idTahunBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend", options);

  var start = 1;
  var end = 12;
  var options = "";
  for (var month = start; month <= end; month++) {
   options += "<option>" + month + "</option>";
  }
  document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend", options);

  var startkiri = $('#idTahunBerlaku :selected').val();

  var start = 1;
  var end = 12;
  var options = "";
  for (var month = start; month <= end; month++) {
   options += "<option>" + month + "</option>";
  }
  document.getElementById("idBulanBerlakuS").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend", options);
  
  $('#idBtnSimpanSimpan')
    .click(
      function() {
       if ($('#idPenerbit').val().trim() == ""
         || $('#idtrainingName').val().trim() == "") {
        alert("ISI SEMUA FORM TERLEBIH DAHULU");
       } else {
        if ($('#idTahunBerlaku').val() > $(
          '#idTahunBerlakuS').val()) {
         alert("TAHUN BERLAKU MULAI TIDAK BOLEH LEBIH KECIL DARI BERLAKU SAMPAI");
        } else {
         debugger;
         $("input, textarea").each(function(){
            $(this).val(jQuery.trim($(this).val()));
         });
         var vDatasertifikasi = $(
           '#idFrmAddSertifikasi').serialize();
         alert(vDatasertifikasi);
         debugger;
         $
           .ajax({
            url : '/savesertifikasi',
            type : 'POST',
            data : vDatasertifikasi,
            dataType : "json",

            success : function(model) {
             debugger;
             if (model.status == "berhasil") {
              alert("Data berhasil disimpan");
              $(
                '#idMdlNewSertifikasi')
                .modal('hide');

              
              window.location = './sertifikasi'
              debugger;

             } else {
              alert("Data salah");
             }
            },
            error : function(model) {
             debugger;
            }
           });
        }
       }
      });

  //   DISABLE PILIHAN
  $(".clSelectKiri").change(function() {
   if ($('#idTahunBerlaku').val() && $('#idBulanBerlaku').val()) {
    $(".clTgglKanan").removeAttr("disabled");
   } else {
    $(".clTgglKanan").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
  }).trigger("change");
 </script>
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="idFrmAddSertifikasi" method="post">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
     <!-- LEVEL 1 / KIRI -->
     <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <label for="SertifikasiName" class="control-label">Nama
        Sertifikasi<sup>*</sup>
       </label>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
         <input type="text" class="form-control clborderbiru"
          maxlength="50" id="idtrainingName" name="certificate_name"
          placeholder="" title="MAKS. KARAKTER 50">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
       <label for="schoolName" class="control-label">Berlaku
        Mulai</label>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
           <select class="form-control clborderbiru clSelectKiri"
            id="idBulanBerlaku" name="valid_start_month">
            <option value="0" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
             Bulan -</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
           <select class="form-control clborderbiru clSelectKiri"
            id="idTahunBerlaku" name="valid_start_year">
            <option value="0" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
             Tahun -</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div>

     <!-- LEVEL 2 / KANAN -->
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">

      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <label for="organizer" class="control-label">Penerbit<sup>*</sup></label>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
         <input type="text" class="form-control clborderbiru"
          id="idPenerbit" name="publisher" placeholder="">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
       <label for="schoolName" class="control-label">Berlaku
        Sampai</label>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
           <select class="form-control clTgglKanan clborderbiru"
            id="idBulanBerlakuS" name="until_month">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
             Bulan -</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
           <select class="form-control clTgglKanan clborderbiru"
            id="idTahunBerlakuS" name="until_year">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
             Tahun -</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <label for="notes" class="control-label">Catatan</label>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
       <textarea class="form-control clborderbiru" id="idCatatan"
        rows="6" name="notes"></textarea>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-10">
     <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn clBtnMdl" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn clBtnMdl" id="idBtnSimpanSimpan">Simpan</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to clear the content of the select before modifying data.

insertAdjacentHTML simply inserts into the DOM at specified location. So you have to clear existing  elements before adding your modifications.

```
$("#idTahunBerlaku").change(
            function() {
                var startkiri = parseInt($(this).val());
                var start = startkiri;
                var end = startkiri + 10;
                var options = "";
                for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
                    options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
                }
                //Empties existing options.
                $("#idTahunBerlakuS").empty();
                //Appends '- Pilih Bulan -'. You can ignore this if you don't need it.
                $('#idTahunBerlakuS').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",'').text('- Pilih Bulan -'));
                document.getElementById("idTahunBerlakuS").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);
            });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok so from what i saw from your code, i just needed to add that empty syntax on my code. So i added the empty inside of my loop. 
From your code my placeholder becoming an option and not hidden, btw thankyou so much for your help :)

Comment: You do not have to call it from inside the loop.. Calling it once will clear every element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from the comment i've said before, i just added a little thing inside of my loop without changing anything. Which is works and it didn't make my "placeholder" to be an option.

```js
$("#idTahunBerlaku").change(
    function() {
     var startkiri = parseInt($(this).val());
     var start = startkiri;
     var end = startkiri + 10;
     var options = "";
     for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
      options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
       $("#idTahunBerlakuS").empty();
     }
     document.getElementById("idTahunBerlakuS")
       .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);
    });
```